# Swift - How can I test with generic?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

I wanna unittest with generics.
But I can't think of a way.

My code is as below, and I want to test the part `prepare()`.

```
class A_ViewModel {
    var useCase: UseCaseProtocol = UseCase()
    var item: A_CellModel = .init()
    
    // I want to unittest prepare()
    func prepare() {
        // logic....
        
        // and call calcuate
        useCase.calculate(item: item)
    }
}

protocol TestableProtocol {
    var testProperty: Bool { get set }
}

class A_CellModel: TestableProtocol {
    var testProperty: Bool = false
}

protocol UseCaseProtocol {
    func calculate<T: TestableProtocol>(item: T)
}

class UseCase: UseCaseProtocol {
    func calculate<T: TestableProtocol>(item: T) {
        // logic......
    }
}
```

However, since `calcaulte(item:)` in usecase uses generic, it is necessary to hand over the clear type (A_CellModel).

In that case, there is a dependence between A_ViewModel and A_CellModel, which makes it difficult to test the unit.

In order to test `prepare()`, should `calcaulte(item:)` give up generic?
Should I use existential type?

Comment: This question may be too abstract to get good answers. How to handle this depends a great deal on what all these protocols are for. It is likely that they're mis-designed (this is a very common mistake). It's unclear what kind of test you're having trouble writing (since A_ViewModel creates its own internal A_CellModel, it's not clear what you mean by "it is necessary to hand over a clear type." In this code, A_CellModel is an implementation detail, so it's not clear why you're testing it through A_ViewModel (you shouldn't). Making this more concrete would help.

Comment: (If you don't want A_ViewModel to be coupled with A_CellModel, do you have a second implementation of CellModel in mind? Don't add generics that don't have a clear purpose. "Decoupling" is not by itself a purpose if you don't have more than one implementation in mind. (If A_CellModel and TestableProtocol have exactly the same list of methods, you probably haven't actually decoupled anything; you've just added indirection.)

Comment: Also it isn't made clear what it is about `prepare` that you want to test — especially given that you've omitted all of it.

Comment: Based on what you have here there is no need for `calculate(item:)` to be generic. Why did you want that in the first place? `TestableProtocol` doesn't have any associated types.